# Why solr RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory dont work?

Tags: solr, token

My schema.xml is splitting product name and then uses RemoveDuplicate to remove duplicated words after split.

```
    <fieldType name="type_name" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|| " />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
```

And in query analyzer I see that RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory did absolutely nothing to duplicated words. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory) you will see that it only removes duplicates at the same position, which is not the case here.

Comment: How can duplicate exist in same position? What can cause it?

Comment: Like the Wiki says, stemming tokens in synonyms with similar root for example.

Comment: and is there a filter that remove duplicate without considering position?