# how to remove duplicated tokens in solr

Tags: solr, duplicates

Followup question to [Why solr RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory dont work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329470/why-solr-removeduplicatestokenfilterfactory-dont-work)

How I can make solr remove duplicated words regardless of word position?

For example:

```
Field value:                    text word word text word word
Expected tokens after X filter: text word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to write your own [TokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.html) to achieve this. One thing that might not be straightforward is the handling of the [position increment](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/PositionIncrementAttribute.html) (in case your are interested in running span of phrase queries over this field). If you don't know how to get started, you can look at [StopFilter implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.java#StopFilter).

Answer (score -1):

I've created a new filter class from "FilteringTokenFilter". The task is pretty simple.  I would check before adding into the list.

I have created a simple plugin [Eliminate duplicate words](https://github.com/volkan/lucene-solr-filter-eliminateduplicate)

To load the plugins, JAR files (along with EliminateDuplicate-*.jar, which can be created by executing mvn package command or https://github.com/volkan/lucene-solr-filter-eliminateduplicate/tree/master/solr/lib) in a lib directory in the Solr Home directory. The location for the lib directory is near the solr.xml file.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen thanks for feedback. I have updated post.

Comment: Works fine for the first time a query/document is analyzed. But the duplicate tokens are remembered in subsequent calls to the analyzer.