# Remove duplicates without considering position

Tags: search, solr, indexing

Is there any Filter Factory that can be used to remove duplicates without considering positions?

I cannot use the RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory because it considers positions [[stack]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329470/why-solr-removeduplicatestokenfilterfactory-dont-work).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove duplicated tokens in solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330632/how-to-remove-duplicated-tokens-in-solr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with lots of duplicate values within fields where I wanted them to be unique. The solution was to add a processor to the **solrconfig.xml** file. Below is the example. Every value for the fields listed will be unique. My field names are *ingredient_substance, active_moiety* ...

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
    <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <lst name="fields">
            <str>ingredient_substance</str>
            <str>active_moiety</str>
            <str>generic_medicine</str>
            <str>inactive_ingredient_substance</str>
        </lst>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```